# How to filter an object in rails so that only the user that created it or an admin can destroy that object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud, before-filter

I have a simple rails apps where users can create quotes (such as, “Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I’m not sure about the universe.” ― Albert Einstein, etc).

I'd like only the users that created the quote, or the admin to be able to edit and delete the quote.

Currently I have a before filter that sets the user that created the quote that looks like this:

`before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy`

Here's my [Quotes controller](https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/269374e069bbc8887b267c384ae94921):

```
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_artist,   only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :new, :destroy, :update, :edit ]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def index
    @quotes = Quote.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 12)
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quote = Quote.new
  end

  def create
    @quote = current_user.quotes.build(quote_params)
    if @quote.save
      flash[:success] = "Quote created!"
      redirect_to @quote
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @quote.update(quote_params)
      flash[:success] = "Quote updated"
      redirect_to @quote
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @quote.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Quote deleted"
    redirect_back(fallback_location: browse_path)
  end

  private

    def set_artist
      @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    end

    def quote_params
      params.require(:quote).permit(:content, :source, :topic_id, :speaker_id)
    end

    def correct_user
      @quote = current_user.quotes.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @quote.nil?
    end
end
```

What is the idiomatically-correct way to do this in Rails? Should I do something like this:

```
def correct_user
  if user.admin?
    @quote = current_user.quotes.find_by(id: params[:id])
  else
   @quote = current_user.quotes.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end
  redirect_to root_url if @quote.nil?
end
```

Is there a more succinct or Rails-way to do this that I'm missing? Also, how do you ensure that only the user that created the quote is able to delete it or edit it? Does my `correct_user` method already cover that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could check if the user is admin or if the user.id is the same as the quote.user_id, in such case you return true, by using `||` you return true if any of the two expressions returns true, so you could do something like:

```
def correct_user
  current_user.admin? || current_user.id == @quote.user_id
end
```

So you could create a helper method that redirects in case the user is not an admin or isn't the quote author/owner:

```
before_action :check_permission, only: %i[edit destroy]

def correct_user
  current_user.admin? || current_user.id == @quote.user_id
end

def check_permission
  redirect_back(fallback_location: browse_path) unless correct_user
end
```

With a before callback you could check in edit and destroy and any other if some of those two expressions are evaluated as true.

Answer (score 2):

I would set two before actions.

```
before_action :resource, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :allow_admin, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

*First would find quote resource*

```
def resource
  @quote = current_user.quotes.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

*Other would allow admin access to resource*

```
def allow_admin
  if current_user.admin? && @quote.nil?
    @quote = Quote.find_by(id: params[:id])
    # Search all quotes, as admin has access to all
  elsif @quote.nil?
    redirect_to root_url
  end
end
```